# Inserting the same table several times

Tags: tables

I'd like to insert the same table in my document multiple times, however I don't want different numbering or labels.

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX. This looks like the same question as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115808, does the suggested solution work for you?